# Getting the text value from cells of a table when scraping recursive structure

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm looking for a function that given a pair os HTML tags, returns the text inside them. Ideally I would like it to be recursive:

Examples:

Given

```
<a href="/wiki/Asset_management" title="It's Asset management">Asset management</a>
```

returns

```
Asset management
```

Given

```
<a href="/wiki/Asset_management" title="Same Asset management"><p>Recursive Asset management</p></a>
```

returns

```
Recursive Asset management
```

Given

```
<p><a href="/wiki/Asset_management" title="Same Asset management">Again Asset management</a></p>
```

returns

```
Again Asset management
```

Here is the code I have:

```
    list_of_table_rows = tbl.findAll('tr')

    for tr in list_of_table_rows[1:]:

        th_list = tr.find("th")
        td_list = tr.find("td")

        if th_list is None or td_list is None:
            continue



        th_str = th.text
        td_str = td.contents

        # NOW THE PROBLEM IS td_str IS A LIST OF A BUNCH OF THINGS.

        #PLAIN TEXT, BR TAG, LINKS, PARAGRAPHS, ETC.

        #I WANT TO BE ABLE TO GET THAT PLAIN TEXT FOR LINKS AND PARAGRAPHS


        for element in td_str:
           if element == "<br/":
              continue
           # here...
```

The input should be a String, not a Tag or any other object. My trouble is the recursion.

---

**UPDATE:** This is an example of the data I am actually working with. The goal is to pull information from Wikipedia Infoboxes. The problem is some of the information in the Infobox are links or paragraphs. For example, in this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_Sachs

```
<tr><th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Founders</th><td 
class="agent" style="line-height:1.35em;"><a 
href="/wiki/Marcus_Goldman" title="Marcus Goldman">Marcus Goldman</a> . 
<br /><a href="/wiki/Samuel_Sachs" title="Samuel Sachs">Samuel 
Sachs</a></td></tr><tr>
```

Let's say we want to find who the Founders are. I only want the text in the elements. In this case a list containing Marcus Goldman and Samuel Sachs. I have also tried `read_html` from Pandas, but that concatenates the strings together and I don't want that to happen (its output is "Marcus GoldmanSamuel Sachs")

Comment: can you also paste the html you are working on and the expected results. The ones you give have no relation to your sample code

Comment: @BittoBennichan Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using `.findChildren`. It's not the full solution, but you can possibly use this to add on to @Bitto Bennichan solution

```
import bs4

html = '''<tr><th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Founders</th><td 
class="agent" style="line-height:1.35em;"><a 
href="/wiki/Marcus_Goldman" title="Marcus Goldman">Marcus Goldman</a> . 
<br /><a href="/wiki/Samuel_Sachs" title="Samuel Sachs">Samuel 
Sachs</a></td></tr><tr>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all('tr')

founders = []
for row in rows:
    children = row.findChildren("a" , recursive=True, text=True)
    for child in children:
        child_text = child.text.split('\n')
        child_text = [ x.strip() for x in child_text ]
        child_text = ' '.join(child_text)
        founders.append(child_text)
```